# Caliburn Micro: no target found for method in Windows Phone template

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, caliburn.micro

I have a Windows Phone 8 app with a `RadDataBoundListBox` and an item template containing a context menu

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListboxItem">
    <Grid>
         <telerikPrimitives:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu>
                <telerikPrimitives:RadContextMenu IsFadeEnabled="False" x:Name="Menu"
                                      IsZoomEnabled="False">
                    <telerikPrimitives:RadContextMenuItem Content="{Binding LocalizedResources.Delete, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
                                <micro:ActionMessage MethodName="Delete">
                                    <micro:Parameter Value="{Binding Id}" />
                                </micro:ActionMessage>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </telerikPrimitives:RadContextMenuItem>
                </telerikPrimitives:RadContextMenu>
            </telerikPrimitives:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu>
...
</DataTemplate>
```

and a public Delete(int) method in my ViewModel. When I click the Delete button in the context menu, I get `no target found for method`.

I guess the problem is the context menu (visual tree) and some more Caliburn "magic" is needed to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to add a name to the root element of the view (e.g: `x:Name="Page"`) and to add this to the `RadContextMenu`

```
<telerikPrimitives:RadContextMenu micro:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding ElementName=Page, Path=DataContext}" ...
```